# Increasing maximum contract size with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, eip170

I want to deploy a large contract on my own test chain and circumvent EIP170's contract size limit of 24576 Byte. Ganache has `--allowUnlimitedContractSize` for this. Is the same possible with geth?

Comment: I'd imagine geth doesn't impose restrictions - only the underlying blockchain (ganache)? Or perhaps Geth has some limits for user-friendliness but unsure.

Comment: What is used gas when you deploy your contract on Ganache? What is the gas limit on your private chain? @UTF-8

Comment: @alper Gas used for deployment is 12'200'000. Gas limit: I always push the gas limit on my private chains up using many calls to a function with a for loop to burn gas until it's as high as I need it to be, so in this case I'd push it to about 15'000'000 to be safe.

Comment: I am able to deploy a contract that is around 6M. But as @Ismael said, if your contract exceeds 32 kbytes, you can divide your contract into multiple. Even if you able to manage to deploy your contract, in long run, it will be inefficient, so you should optimize your contract, and try to develop based on the current gas limit in the mainnet which is around 10 million (https://etherscan.io/chart/gaslimit.)  today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately geth cannot be easily configured for contracts of arbitrary size.

The [`MaxCodeSize`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/release/1.9/params/protocol_params.go#L111) constant was added by [SpuriousDragon fork](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-607). And its application is controlled by a genesis parameter `EIP158Block`. In theory disabling SpuriousDragon from genesis will allow contracts of arbitrary size.

Another issue is that geth limits transactions to a [maximum size of 32 kbytes](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/release/1.9/core/tx_pool.go#L514-L516). This limit is hardcoded and to change it you have to compile your own version of geth.

```
func (pool *TxPool) validateTx(tx *types.Transaction, local bool) error {
    // Heuristic limit, reject transactions over 32KB to prevent DOS attacks
    if tx.Size() > 32*1024 {
        return ErrOversizedData
    }
```